# Any plans for Bitcoin Core app to integrate Hardware Wallet support?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, full-node, hardware-wallet

So I could use the full node and wallet easily integrated with a HW wallet and avoid security exploits?
Recently had a case of someone that had all his wallet stolen probably because of a keylogger - not a good experience for a noob that was just starting and was trusting the "best" full(complete) node Bitcoin (don't trust, verify) experience.

We know the key creation is flawed from the user perspective and this is something that already has a solution but still not implemented into the full node wallet client. Any plans for adding this extra layer of security for non-technical end-users?

Answer (score 1):

There currently are no plans to support hardware wallets in Core. However this does not mean that it will not happen, it just means that no one is currently working on supporting them. Unfortunately there are no full node wallets which support hardware wallets. But I am working on hardware wallet support in Armory so you can look forward to that coming out in a few months (probably).

Comment: Monero added hardware wallet support to their full node wallet - since it's the only way to use Monero with their privacy features and they wanted to provide users with the best experience possible. Maybe their work on code can help integrate HW to Bitcoin?

Comment: Their work won't be particularly useful since the Monero APIs are different from the ones for Bitcoin and the approach that they used for hardware wallet integration is not one that the Bitcoin Core developers are willing to use. They chose to integrate device drivers directly into their software, however the Bitcoin Core devs do not want to do that as it will require maintaining vendor specific code. Rather what we are doing is calling an external binary that has the drivers implemented so that there is no need to maintain vendor specific code in Bitcoin Core itself.